# Alternative to React useLocation hook for page update based on url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

This is a tricky problem.

**A bit of info**:
 I can have multiple collections of multiple images and a specific header logo for each collection. 
My collection url looks like this `/collection/{collectionId}/item/{itemId}`

```
const MyApp = () => {
    // unrelated code
    return(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <SiteLayout>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

and

```
const SiteLayout = () => {
    location = useLocation()
    collectionId = location.pathname.split('/')[2] //gives me the collection Alias

    const [collData, setCollData] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        const getCollectionData = async() => {
            //fetch collection data
            //setCollData(fetched data)
        }
        getCollectionData()
    }, [collectionId])

    return(
        <CollectionContext.Provider value={collData}>
            <div className='mainContainer'>
                <div className='headerContainer'>
                    <Header/>
                </div>
                <div className='mainContent'>
                    <Route exact path='/collection/:collectionId' component={CollectionViewPage}>
                    <Route exact path='/collection/:collectionId/item/:itemId' component={ItemViewPage}
                </div>
                <div className='footerContainer'>
                    <Footer/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </CollectionContext.Provider>
    )

}
export default SiteLayout
```

**My thoughts:**

- I set it up this way, because I cant use `useLocation()` outside of `<BrowserRouter>` and I want to update my collectionContext (which contains information about a the collection I'm on, including the collection specific header logo) when the `collectionId` changes, which is part of the `location`

**My issue:**

- When I move from item to item, *within* a collection, the header and everything else still re-renders, for example

  from -- `/collection/`**collection1**/`item`/**1**
  to -- `/collection/`**collection1**/`item`/**2**
- **My thoughts:** This header shouldn't update because the `collectionId` never changed. *However*, when I look at the Profiler in React dev tools, it says the Header changed because the parent changed, following it up to `<Route>` which changed because it's state (`location`) changed.

**What I'm looking for**: How do I refactor this to update when the `collectionId` changes, but not every time the `location` changes? I need this because (many things, but for simplicity) I want the header to update when I change collections, so that it can use the correct logo, but I would like to prevent the `<Header>` from re-rendering if I'm navigating around **within** the collection.

**Something else I've tried**:
I've tried ripping out `useLocation` and instead using `window.location.pathname` but nothing will update.

Comment: If Header and CollectionViewPage are functional components maybe you can wrap hem in [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html#reactmemo) If they still re render then check the props that are passed, look at what you need and maybe create a container that only picks what you actually need and not props that did change but are not used.

Comment: @HMR Found a solution based off your suggestion (noted in the answer below) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solved

---

Using the suggestion from @HMR in response to the original question:

> If Header and CollectionViewPage are functional components maybe you can wrap [them] in React.memo If they still re render [...] look at what you need and maybe create a container that only picks what you actually need...

---

**Implementation:**

By adding a middle layer, I am able to split `location`, and then memoize `SiteLayout` based on whatever part of it I would like.

```
const MyApp = () => {
    // unrelated code
    return(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <LocationPartition>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
export default MyApp
```

where in `LocationPartition` (could probably use a better name):

```
const LocationPartition = () => {
    const location = useLocation()
    const collectionId = location.pathname.split('/')[2]
    return(
        <SiteLayout collection={collectionId}/>
    )
}
export default LocationPartition
```

and so in `SiteLayout`, I can now memoize based off the `collection` prop passed from `LocationPartition`

```
const SiteLayout = memo(({collection})) => {

    const [collData, setCollData] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        const getCollectionData = async() => {
            //fetch collection data
            //setCollData(fetched data)
        }
        getCollectionData()
    }, [collection])

    return(
        <CollectionContext.Provider value={collData}>
            <div className='mainContainer'>
                <div className='headerContainer'>
                    <Header/>
                </div>
                <div className='mainContent'>
                    <Route exact path='/collection/:collectionId' component={CollectionViewPage}>
                    <Route exact path='/collection/:collectionId/item/:itemId' component={ItemViewPage}
                </div>
                <div className='footerContainer'>
                    <Footer/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </CollectionContext.Provider>
    )

}
export default SiteLayout
```

And **lo and behold** ... React Profiler now only shows re-renders where I want them!